# ContentResolver.update () NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-contentprovider

I am trying to write a calendar provider for Android. I have created a class `Event` with methods to create and update events in the Calendar Provider API.

When I attempt to update an event in the API using `ContentResolver.update ()`, I encounter a `NullPointerException`. According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#update(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)), the `ContentResolver.update ()` method is meant to throw `NullPointerException` only if uri or values arguments are null (the first two arguments). I have confirmed using a debugger that neither of those are null when the crash happens, and therefore this method is not supposed to throw an exception.

I have stepped through the code of this method in the debugger, to try and figure out which value is null that isn't supposed to be, but that wasn't helpful either. The error seems to originate from some native code in the content provider system and then be unpackaged and thrown at some point later. I might be wrong about that though.

I have also tried to find information using an internet search engine, as well as searching this site, and I wasn't able to find anybody who had the same problem as me before.

I will include some relevant code below. I think it would be pretty difficult to come up with a working minimal example because it requires a lot of different parts to work the Calendar Provider API.

Is there anybody more familiar with Android and the Content Provider system who might be able to share some related knowledge or pointers to help figure out what's wrong?

```java
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 26727
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3027)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3005)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2981)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:653)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.update(ContentProviderClient.java:417)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:2412)
        at com.example.myapp.model.Event.update(Event.java:337)
        at com.example.myapp.model.Event.save(Event.java:287)
        at com.example.myapp.model.Ical.loadEvent(Ical.java:269)
        at com.example.myapp.model.Ical.load(Ical.java:99)
        at com.example.myapp.model.Ical.load(Ical.java:85)
        at com.example.myapp.model.CalendarSyncAdapter.readEmail(CalendarSyncAdapter.java:183)
        at com.example.myapp.model.CalendarSyncAdapter.syncDown(CalendarSyncAdapter.java:157)
        at com.example.myapp.model.CalendarSyncAdapter.onPerformSync(CalendarSyncAdapter.java:78)
        at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:354)
```

```java
    private void update (ContentResolver contentResolver)
    {
        Uri uri = CONTENT_URI;
        uri = Utils.asSyncAdapter (
                uri,
                calendar.account ().name,
                calendar.account ().type
        );
        uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId (uri, id);

        ContentValues contentValues = contentValues ();
        contentResolver.update (uri, contentValues, null, null);
    }

    private ContentValues contentValues ()
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues ();

        cv.put (CALENDAR_ID, calendar.id ());
        cv.put (ORGANIZER, organiser);
        cv.put (TITLE, title);
        cv.put (EVENT_LOCATION, location);
        cv.put (DESCRIPTION, description);
        cv.put (EVENT_COLOR, colour);
        cv.put (DTSTART, startTime);
        if (endTime != -1)
        {
            cv.put (DTEND, endTime);
        }
        cv.put (EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID ());
        if (endTimeZone != null) {
            cv.put (EVENT_END_TIMEZONE, endTimeZone.getID ());
        }
        cv.put (DURATION, duration);
        cv.put (ALL_DAY, allDay ? 1 : 0);
        cv.put (RRULE, rrule);
        cv.put (RDATE, rdate);
        cv.put (EXRULE, exrule);
        cv.put (EXDATE, exdate);
        if (originalEvent != null)
        {
            cv.put (ORIGINAL_ID, originalEvent.id);
            cv.put (ORIGINAL_SYNC_ID, originalEvent.syncId);
            cv.put (ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME, originalEvent.startTime);
            cv.put (ORIGINAL_ALL_DAY, originalEvent.allDay ? 1 : 0);
        }
        cv.put (ACCESS_LEVEL, accessLevel);
        cv.put (AVAILABILITY, availability);
        cv.put (GUESTS_CAN_MODIFY, guestsCanModify ? 1 : 0);
        cv.put (GUESTS_CAN_INVITE_OTHERS, guestsCanInviteOthers ? 1 : 0);
        cv.put (GUESTS_CAN_SEE_GUESTS, guestsCanSeeGuests ? 1 : 0);
        cv.put (UID_2445, icalUid);

        cv.put (DIRTY, dirty);
        cv.put (MUTATORS, mutators);
        cv.put (_SYNC_ID, syncId);

        return cv;
    }

    // (In Utils.java)
    static Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
        return uri.buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true")
                .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
                .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not setting the "last modified" timestamp on the event. This is required for the update to work.

You can set it like this:

```
cv.put(Events.LAST_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

If you don't set this timestamp, the provider will assume that
the event hasn't been modified and won't update it.

Comment: I tried this suggestion and got the same error again, so it must be some other problem. Thanks so much for the answer though. I didn't know I was supposed to set a last modified time. The Android documentation seems to be a bit lacking in some places.